# Merging only tested data back to the original dataframe by index

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

After training my model now i want to see my original dataframe along with y_pred values.

```
y_hats = model.predict(X_test) #got the predicted values

y_test['preds'] = y_hats #trying to join them (preds column next to y_test)(whose index is 
                          #what needs to be connected back to original dataframe)

df_out = pd.merge(df,y_test[['preds']],how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

But the result I get is all y pred values are null. y_test has the correct index values to be connected to original dataframe. but when i create the 'preds' column its actually an array hence it doesnt work. And when I create a df out of the preds array the index resets, obviously. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you print y_hats.head() and see what output do you see and paste the output here as well, for better understanding.

Comment: @zenwraight, just uploaded a pic of it

Comment: is it possible to share the whole code @Zee ?